# Attach user form to UDF which is created in system form

Tags: sapb1

I'm learning sap b1. I have created a field in marketing document. When I enter any value in this field and press on tab button, my user defined form should be open with the data from OITM table and find textbox and highlight the record with value which I entered in UDF.I already seen sample of SimpleForm but not getting anything from it. How can I achieve this?I'm using C# in VS. Plz help me with some examples/hints/code.  I would be really grateful for your help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use choosefromlist controll, you should set Choosefromlist to item object 4, then in EditText properties choose this CFL and in the Alias field enter table filed which you want to filter when tab is pressed.